# Getting child element in elemement?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I want to make a "niveau-picker" widget for my Ionic/AngularJS application. It should look something like this:

[image]

My current HTML:

```
<niveau-selector>

  <button class="plus-minus-button icon ion-minus"></button>

  <table id="niveau_selector">
        <tr>
          <td><div style="min-height:20px" id="bin_1">.</div></td>
          <td><div style="min-height:30px" id="bin_2">.</div></td>
          <td><div style="min-height:40px" id="bin_3">.</div></td>
          <td><div style="min-height:50px" id="bin_4">.</div></td>
          <td><div style="min-height:60px" id="bin_5">.</div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

  <button class="plus-minus-button icon ion-plus plus"></button>

</niveau-selector>
```

Now I want to make an Angular directive to handle it. But I don't know how to get hold of the different DOM elements. Each time the plus button is pressed the next bin should become yellow. This is what I have:

```
app.directive('niveauSelector', function() {
    var linkFn;
    linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {

        binOne = angular.element.?????
        binTwo = angular.element.?????
        ....
        plus  = angular.element.??
        minus = angular.element.??

        set_niveau = function(niveau) {
          ... set colors on bin-elements.. 
        };

        plus.on('click', set_niveau);
        minus.on('click', set_niveau);
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: linkFn
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with:

```
binOne = angular.element(document.querySelector('#bin_1'));
```

Comment: It actually works, but chrome still puts out an error: Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!